# Floating div not displaying background color when i am not using overflow?

Tags: html, css, css-float, overflow

**HTML**:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
      <div id="slider"></div>

      <div id="left"></div>

      <div id="right"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**:

```css
#wrapper
{
  background:blue;
  width:990px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#content
{
  width:990px;
  height:auto;
}

#slider
{
  width:990px;
/* slider jquery   */
  height:auto;
}

#left
{
  float:left;
  width:490px;
}

#right
{
  float:right;
  width:490px;
}
```

**Live demo: [Tinkerbin](http://tinkerbin.com/9sP3PJxp)**

But in left and right div blue color is not displaying ,

If i am giving `overflow:hidden` to `wrapper` then its work fine.
Is it necessary to give `overflow` to parent of floating div?

why?

Comment: Pretty impossible to answer without seeing more CSS or, better, a JS Fiddle of the problem. Are you sure the divs actually have any dimensions? If not, you won't see anything.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One of the common problems we face when coding with `float based layouts` is that the `wrapper container` doesn't expand to the `height of the child floating elements.` The typical solution to fix this is by adding an element with `clear float after the floating elements or adding a clearfix to the wrapper`. But you can also use the `overflow property to fix this problem`. It's not a new CSS trick either. It's been documented before long long ago.

Answer (score 7):

When you float an element it appears as if it's lost it's height. So element is in blue color, you just don't see it. Either you give him height, or style your wrapper with `overflow: hidden`. And if you want background color for elements it's `background-color: blue`. `color: blue` is for letters.

Comment: +1 for spotting the `color`/`background-color` discrepancy. However it's not true to say that floating removes an element's height; any explicitly-set height will still remain, as will any implied, forced height caused by it snapping to its contents. What you probably meant was that the container OF floated elements will appear to lose height, because floated elements do not cause containers to stretch.

Comment: sorry actually i given background-color,its working fine when i am giving overflow,bt without overflow ,even i give height also not working

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the [**clearfix**](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) if you have floating elements inside a `<div>`.

> The problem happens when a floated element is within a container box, that element does not automatically force the container’s height adjust to the floated element. When an element is floated, its parent no longer contains it because the float is removed from the flow.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="slider">slider</div>
    <div id="left">left</div>
    <div id="right">right</div>
    <div class="clear"></div> <!-- THIS -->
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.clear { clear: both }
```

**Live demo: [Tinkerbin](http://tinkerbin.com/8cfMG32D)**